# Rails form validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation

I have a Rails app that lets a user construct a database query by filling out an extensive form.  I wondered the best practice for checking form parameters in Rails.  Previously, I have had my `results` method (the one to which the form submits) do the following:

```
if params[:name] && !params[:name].blank?
  @name = params[:name]
else
  flash[:error] = 'You must give a name'
  redirect_to :action => 'index'
  return
end
```

But for several form fields, seeing this repeated for each one got tiresome.  I couldn't just stick them all in some loop to check for each field, because the fields are set up differently:

- a single key:  `params[:name]`
- a key and a sub-key:  `params[:image][:font_size]`
- only expect some form fields to be filled out if another field was set

Etc.  This was also repetitive, because I was setting `flash[:error]` for each missing/invalid parameter, and redirecting to the same URL for each one.  I switched to using a `before_filter` that checks for all necessary form parameters and only returns true if everything's okay.  Then the my `results` method continues, and variables are just assigned flat-out, with no checking involved:

```
@name = params[:name]
```

In my `validate_form` method, I have sections of code like the following:

```
if (
  params[:analysis_type][:to_s] == 'development' ||
  params[:results_to_generate].include?('graph')
)
  {:graph_type => :to_s, :graph_width => :to_s,
   :theme => :to_s}.each do |key, sub_key|
    unless params[key] && params[key][sub_key]
      flash[:error] = "Cannot leave '#{Inflector.humanize(key)}' blank"
      redirect_to(url)
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

I was just wondering if I'm going about this in the best way, or if I'm missing something obvious when it comes to parameter validation.  I worry this is still not the most efficient technique, because I have several blocks where I assign a value to `flash[:error]`, then redirect to the same URL, then return false.

*Edit to clarify:*  The reason I don't have this validation in model(s) currently is for two reasons:

- I'm not trying to gather data from the user in order to create or update a row in the database.  None of the data the user submits is saved after they log out.  It's all used right when they submit it to search the database and generate some stuff.
- The query form takes in data pertaining to several models, and it takes in other data that doesn't pertain to a model at all.  E.g. graph type and theme as shown above do not connect to any model, they just convey information about how the user wants to display his results.

*Edit to show improved technique:*  I make use of application-specific exceptions now, thanks to Jamis Buck's [Raising the Right Exception article](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/3/7/raising-the-right-exception).  For example:

```
def results
  if params[:name] && !params[:name].blank?
    @name = params[:name]
  else
    raise MyApp::MissingFieldError
  end

  if params[:age] && !params[:age].blank? && params[:age].numeric?
    @age = params[:age].to_i
  else
    raise MyApp::MissingFieldError
  end
rescue MyApp::MissingFieldError => err
  flash[:error] = "Invalid form submission: #{err.clean_message}"
  redirect_to :action => 'index'
end
```

Comment: I think you don't have to use params[:name] and !params[:name].blank? in your condtions. !params[:name].blank? is enough. params[:name] return false if it is nil (there is no such parameter) and params[:name].blank? return true if it is nil or empty.

Comment: You get a NoMethodError.  I could override NilClass to add #blank? to it, I suppose.

irb(main):002:0> params = {:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3}
=> {:c=>3, :a=>1, :b=>2}
irb(main):003:0> !params[:name].blank?
NoMethodError: undefined method `blank?' for nil:NilClass
        from (irb):3

Comment: No Ruby here, only Rails. *deleted tag*

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could try active_form (http://github.com/cs/active_form/tree/master/lib/active_form.rb) - just ActiveRecord minus the database stuff. This way you can use all of AR's validation stuff and treat your form like you would any other model.

```
class MyForm < ActiveForm
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_presence_of :graph_size, :if => # ...blah blah 
end

form = MyForm.new(params[:form])
form.validate
form.errors
```

Comment: Is `validates_presence_of :name` an alias for `validates :name, presence: true`? I've only seen the latter in Rails guides.

Comment: To answer my own question, the latter way is a new way to do validations introduced in Rails 3. http://thelucid.com/2010/01/08/sexy-validation-in-edge-rails-rails-3/

Answer (score 8):

Looks like you are doing the validation in the controller, try putting it in the model, it's better suited to that sort of thing.

Comment: As recommended in the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html) as well: "Controller-level validations can be tempting to use, but often become unwieldy and difficult to test and maintain. Whenever possible, it’s a good idea to [keep your controllers skinny](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/10/18/skinny-controller-fat-model), as it will make your application a pleasure to work with in the long run."

Answer (score 2):

If you were to tackle the problem again today, you could create a model for the query parameter set and use Rails' built in validations, Rails 3 makes this a lot easier with ActiveModel::Validations see [this post](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/01/10/activemodel-make-any-ruby-object-feel-like-activerecord/).

Answer (score 1):

### Model

```
class Person 
    include ActiveModel::Validations
    include ActiveModel::Conversion
    extend ActiveModel::Naming

    attr_accessor :name
    attr_accessor :email


    validates_presence_of :name,:message => "Please Provide User Name"
    validates_presence_of :email,:message => "Please Provide Email"
end
```

Note that you don't necessarily need to save/persist the model to validate.

### Controller

```
@person.name= params["name"]
@person.email= params["email"]
@person.valid?
```

One you called .valid? method on the model, the errors will be populated inside @person object. Hence,

### View

```
<%if @person.errors.any? %>
     <%@person.errors.messages.each do|msg| %>
          <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <%=msg[0][1]%>
          </div>
     <%end%>
<%end%>
```