# Rails - Using true and false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following in my controller:

```
if params[:archive] == 'true'
  @archived_new_status = true
else
  @archived_new_status = false
end
```

Then later in create.je.erb do:

```
<% if !@archived_new_status.nil? %>
   xxx.myfuncthatNeedsTrueOrFalse(<%=@archived_new_status%>);
<% end %>
```

That only works when @archived_new_status is true, when it's false that seems to not be getting set as false. When I do a Rails.logger.info on @archived_new_status for false it outputs nothing, if I inspect it, I get false.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

The code in the controller can be written:

```
@archive_new_status = (params[:archive] == 'true')
```

View: I don't understand why you check if the variable is nil; `@archive_new_status` is either true or false, so simply call the JS code (using `to_json` for any argument you have):

```
xxx.myfuncthatNeedsTrueOrFalse(<%= @archived_new_status.to_json %>);
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
<% if !@archived_new_status.blank? %>
   xxx.myfuncthatNeedsTrueOrFalse(<%=@archived_new_status%>);
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks but given the rails.logger outputs above mentioned false is not outputted blank is. Meaning if the IF passed above it would be blank no?

Comment: If you're going to negate a call to `blank?`, you should use `present?` instead.

Comment: ah shoot turns out that HTML doesn't submit input elements that are disabled. that was the issue. dang

Comment: Actually never mind... that wasn't it... Still and issue with a var set to false doesn't output anything... Maybe there is a way with Ruby to say EVALUATE as binary?

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
if params[:archive] && !params[:archive].blank?
    @archived_new_status = params[:archive]
end
```

But you may want to put validation in the model or raise application exceptions. See [Rails form validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361161/rails-form-validation)

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand correctly that somehow the variable `@archived_new_status` is not set? Although, the code you show always sets it to either `true` or `false`.

I would rewrite as follows:

```
@archived_new_status = if params[:archive] == 'true'
  true
else
  false
end
```

The same as the code above, only somewhat simpler (and maybe clearer). Then you could write it even shorter:

```
@archived_new_status = params[:archive] == 'true'
```

(actually this is completely identical to what you showed us).
In your view, you can then be sure that `@archived_new_status` is always set! From the code you showed us, there is no other way. It is either `true` or `false`. So your view becomes:

```
   xxx.myfuncthatNeedsTrueOrFalse(<%= @archived_new_status.to_s %>);
```

(i presume you are calling some javascript function here, with a wanted parameter of either true or false. Are you sure that the value is converted correctly to a string?  --> i added `.to_s` for clarity)

From what you show us, nothing much could be wrong, so to wrap up:

- can you make sure that `@archived_new_status` is set correctly, if not, show the complete code sample
- in the view you are rendering, are you converting the value correctly to a string? can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: `@archived_new_status = params[:archive] == 'true' ? true : false` is identical to `@archived_new_status = params[:archive] == 'true'`

Answer (score 0):

`Rails.logger.info false` incorrectly outputs nothing (see [my answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728130/ruby-rails-dealing-with-a-boolean-false-it-outputs-nothing/4728609#4728609)), so I think that's hiding whatever your real problem is.

ERB `<%= something %>` implicitly calls `something.to_s`, but `false.to_s == 'false'`, so the most likely explanation for what you're seeing is that `@archived_new_status` is somehow not getting set at all, or not getting passed to the view template.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I am taking it as @archived_new_status is a Boolean (true or false)

```
params[:archive] ? @archived_new_status : !@archived_new_status
```