# ruby - rails - Dealing with a Boolean False- It outputs nothing

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have record in my db that is a boolean field (true/false).

The field is archived. When archived is true all these work great to output true:

```
  Rails.logger.info @commentable.archived
  Rails.logger.info @commentable.archived?
  Rails.logger.info !!@commentable.archived?
```

BUT when the archived is false, it outputs nothing for either of the above. How can I get an output of false when the field is FALSE?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `.to_s` on the field?

```
irb(main):001:0> false.to_s
=> "false"
irb(main):002:0> true.to_s
=> "true"
irb(main):003:0>
```

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use `.inspect` for doing output to logging.  I find its output more useful if you get a nil value.

```
ruby-1.8.7-p302 > nil.to_s
 => "" 
ruby-1.8.7-p302 > nil.inspect
 => "nil" 
ruby-1.8.7-p302 > false.to_s
 => "false" 
ruby-1.8.7-p302 > false.inspect
 => "false" 
ruby-1.8.7-p302 >
```

Comment: thanks but this isn't for logging output. that was just used for testing.

Answer (score 1):

`false.to_s == 'false'`, but `Rails.logger.info` seems to do the wrong thing here:

```
> puts true
true
> puts false
false
> Rails.logger.info true
true
> Rails.logger.info false
```